# Phase order parameter interpretation

Tags: coupled-oscillators

This is a basic question regarding the order parameter of a coupled oscillator system.

I am aware that the order parameter $re^{i\phi} = \frac{1}{N} \sum \limits_{j=1}^N e^{i\theta_j}$ measures the synchrony of the N oscillators.

Litterature on the subject tells me that when near synchrony, the real part of the phase order parameter oscillates near 1 as a function of time. This implies that $real(re^{i\phi}) =  r \cos(\phi)$ oscillates near 1, which in terms implies that $\phi \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, but $\phi$ is traversing the entire unit circle so I fail to see how this is possible?

I have obviously mistaken something, but what?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have read that the real part (also true for the imaginary part) oscillates with an amplitude of nearly one.

See what happens when you assume that all the oscillators are in phase: $\theta_i = \theta_1$ for all $i$ and at all times. It follows:

$$r e^{i \phi} = e^{i \theta_1}$$

so that $r = 1$.